# pandas aggregate count in dataframe

Tags: pandas, indexing, dataframe, counting

I have a DataFrame and I am using `.aggregate({'col1': np.sum})`, this will perform a summation of the values in `col1` and aggregate them together. Is it possible to perform a count, something like `.aggregate({'col1': some count function here})`?

Comment: `{'col1': 'count'}` or `{'col1': 'size'}`  or `{'col1': 'nunique'}`  depending on your use case.

Comment: Or `len` (the built-in), which I suggest is the most readable of the bunch.

Comment: `len` is typically slower than `'size'`, as it's a python built-in instead of numpy under the hood.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `'size'`, `'count'`, or `'nunique'` depending on your use case. The differences between them being:

- `'size'`: the count including `NaN` and repeat values.
- `'count'`: the count excluding `NaN` but including repeats.
- `'nunique'`: the count of unique values, excluding repeats and `NaN`.

For example, consider the following DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col0': list('aabbcc'), 'col1': [1, 1, 2, np.nan, 3, 4]})

  col0  col1
0    a   1.0
1    a   1.0
2    b   2.0
3    b   NaN
4    c   3.0
5    c   4.0
```

Then using the three functions described:

```
df.groupby('col0')['col1'].agg(['size', 'count', 'nunique'])

      size  count  nunique
col0                      
a        2      2        1
b        2      1        1
c        2      2        2
```